# How to inject a Spring Data JPA Repository into a Servlet Filter?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using the [Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). I want to use a rewrite rule from a database, so using the `<class-rule class="com.example.Foo" />` configuration, which lets you get rules at runtime. I created a class extending RewriteRule:

```
public class Foo extends RewriteRule {

  @Autowired
  private MyRepository myRepository;

  public boolean init(ServletContext servletContext) {

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public RewriteMatch matches(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    //myRepository is null

    return super.matches(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {

  }
}
```

I'd like to use a Spring Data JPA Repository inside this Foo class, but it looks the repository is null.

How can I inject it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your filter in `web.xml` as usual, except that you will need to provide `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` as the filter class name instead of your actual class name.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Finally, in your ROOT application context, declare a bean pointing to your filter class and with the same name as the filter name provided in `web.xml` in the application context file loaded from `web.xml`:

```
<bean id="urlRewriteFilter" class="org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter"/>
```

Since your filter instance is now managed by Spring, you can inject any Spring managed bean into it.

Comment: Thanks @manish . I'm getting a NullPointerException in the UrlRewriteFilter.getFullVersionString() static method at UrlRewriteFilter.class.getResourceAsStream("build.number.properties");

Comment: That is not related to your original question.  You will find plenty of answers on StackOverflow for `NullPointerException with getResourceAsStream`.  If none of them work, please open a separate question.

Comment: it was working fine without the DelegatingFilterProxy, so it must be related to that.

Comment: setting init-param targetFilterLifecycle=true fixed it. Thanks a bunch!